# CSS not work in MVC dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Im beginner in the ASP.NET MVC. I am add drop down menu , but the CSS does not work correctly. How can I fix it? This is my code:

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.Fields[i], new SelectList(Model.attrs[i].atributeDetails, "AtributeDetailId", "AtDetailVal", int.Parse(Model.Fields[i])), " ", new { Class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled",style = "width:575px;height:25px;font-size:small;" })
```

Comment: Is it the styling in the 'style' tag that's not working or the styles associated with the 'form-control' class that aren't working?

Comment: its not work how can i make it?

Comment: Phrases like *does not work correctly* are very ambiguous. What is the actual result, and how what did you expect instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're saying that the styles associated with the 'form-control' class aren't working then it could be because the 'Class' word needs to be lowercase. I normally use `@class="my-class"`. So maybe try the following:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.Fields[i], new SelectList(Model.attrs[i].atributeDetails, "AtributeDetailId", "AtDetailVal", int.Parse(Model.Fields[i])), " ", new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled",style = "width:575px;height:25px;font-size:small;" })
```